# rosoct wiki, rosoct with octave3.2

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all, my first post here :)

**I'm trying to compile rosoct.**

1. The svn on the [rosoct wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosoct) does not work. After browsing, I found this one: *https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros_experimental/branches/cturtle/rosoct/* Should this be the one on the wiki?
2. Is there some way to make rosoct compile with *octave3.2headers* instead of the older *octave3.0headers*? While compiling with 3.2 I receive the following errors:

`~/ros/rosoct/rosoct.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void RoscppSubscription::dowork(OctaveMsgDeserializer*)’: ~/ros/rosoct/rosoct.cpp:455: error: ‘class uint8NDArray’ has no member named ‘resize_no_fill’ ~/ros/rosoct/rosoct.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void RoscppService::dowork()’: ~/ros/rosoct/rosoct.cpp:582: error: ‘class uint8NDArray’ has no member named ‘resize_no_fill’`

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9234/rosoct-wiki,-rosoct-with-octave3.2/) by [omwdunkley](https://answers.ros.org/users/209/omwdunkley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

FYI: rosoct has been retired, which is why it is no longer present on the wiki.  Also, it is not compatible with ROS Diamondback.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [omwdunkley](https://answers.ros.org/users/209/omwdunkley/) on 2011-03-01**:
Thanks for the info!